# Weighted integrability and global Lipschitz imply weighted boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

My question comes from Page 257 in [Cazenave's Semilinear Schrodinger Equations](http://bookstore.ams.org/cln-10/).

According to my understanding, the author says that if a globally Lipschitz function $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{|x|} |u(x)|^2 \,dx < \infty$, then $e^{|x|}|u(x)|^{d+2}$ is bounded.

I want to know how to prove this. I try some ways (like Riemann sum approximation) to understand whether this is true or not, but they seems to be on the wrong way.

Many thanks for any discussion or idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the way below to understand: The computation may contain some error, please check. 
We  need to show that $\limsup_{x\to\infty}e^{|x|/(d+2)}|u(x)|<\infty$.  If it is false, then for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$, there exits 
$x_n$ such that $|x_n|\to \infty$ and $|u(x_n)|>Ne^{-|x_n|/(d+2)}$. Then, by  globally Lipschitz continuity of $u$, we can choose $r_n<<1$ such that
$|u(x)|>N/2e^{-|x|/(d+2)}$ for all  $x\in B(x_n,r_n)$. It is easy to see that $r_n\sim N e^{-|x_n|/(d+2)}$. Then we have 
$$
\int_{B(x_n,r_n)}e^{|x|}|u(x)|^2 dx\gtrsim N^{d+2}\to \infty 
$$
which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

My proof follows the idea of [Yuhang Chen](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414015):

Let $L$ be the Lipschitz constant of $u$. Suppose $\limsup_{|x| \to \infty} e^{|x|/(d+2)} |u(x)| = \infty$, then for each $M>0$, there is $\{ x_n\}_1^\infty$ with $|x_n| \nearrow \infty$ and $|u(x_n)| > M e^{-|x_n|/(d+2)}$. Let $r_n = \frac{M}{2L} e^{-|x_n|/(d+2)}$, the Lipschitz continuity implies that for each $x \in B_{r_n}(x_n), |u(x)| > \frac{M}{2} e^{-|x_n|/(d+2)}$.

We note that, for large $n$, the set $S:=\{ x \in B_{r_n}(x_n): |x| \geq |x_n| \}$ has measure larger than $\frac{1}{2} m(B_{r_n}(x_n))$, so

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{|x|}|u(x)|^2 dx  \geq \int_{B(x_n,r_n)}e^{|x|}|u(x)|^2 dx \geq \frac{M^2}{4} e^{-2|x_n|/(d+2)} \int_S e^{|x|} dx \geq \frac{M^2}{4} e^{-2|x_n|/(d+2)} \frac{\omega_n}{2} \Big( \frac{M}{2L} \Big)^d e^{-d|x_n|/(d+2)} e^{|x_n|} = \frac{\omega_n L^2}{2} \Big( \frac{M}{2L} \Big)^{d+2}.
$$

Since $M$ is arbitrary, we see a contradiction.

**Remark:**

The constant $\frac{1}{d+2}$ in the exponential decay rate is computed by solving $0 \leq 1 - 2\alpha - d\alpha$ for largest $\alpha$.